# Renderer get current focus

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have created a simple `Renderer` that looks like this

```
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Example.Pages.MaterialPages;
using Example.Droid.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MaterialsListView), typeof(MaterialsListViewRenderer))]
namespace Example.Droid.Renderers
{
   public class MaterialsListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
   {
      public MaterialsListViewRenderer() {}
   }

   internal class ScrollListener : Java.Lang.Object, AbsListView.IOnScrollListener
   {
      public void OnScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { }

      public void OnScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, [GeneratedEnum] ScrollState scrollState)
      {
         if (scrollState == ScrollState.TouchScroll)
         {
            // GET THE CURRENT FOCUSED ELEMENT
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now I need to get the current focus like `getCurrentFocus` in Java.
But how can I do this in Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `Context` of the `ListView` to `Activity`.

```
internal class ScrollListener : Java.Lang.Object, AbsListView.IOnScrollListener
{
    public void OnScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { }

    public void OnScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, [GeneratedEnum] ScrollState scrollState)
    {
        if (scrollState == ScrollState.TouchScroll)
        {
            // GET THE CURRENT FOCUSED ELEMENT
            var focused = ((Activity) view.Context).CurrentFocus;
        }
    }
}
```